# Laravel ServiceProvicder Why would someone register 2 singletons for the same class?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have existing code that I wish to refactor from Laravel 4.2 to 5.5.  The original programmers had something like this for all of their ServiceProviders:

```
use App\UI\Alerts;
class AlertsProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Alerts', function ($app) {
            return new Alerts;
        });

        $this->app->singleton('App\UI\Alerts', function ($app) {
            return $app->make('Alerts');
        });
    }
}
```

What is the purpose to the second singleton?  Is it needed?

Note... My background is not in PHP.

Comment: I mistakenly deleted the UI in the namespace.  I updated use App\Alerts to use App\UI\Alerts;

Comment: If it's the same namespace for both singletons then I really don't see a point in creating 2 singletons of the same class, anyhow, you should probably be best off to search for both app('Alerts') and app('App\UI\Alerts') in your code. If you feel comfortable you can rename all of app('App\UI\Alerts') to app('Alerts') and remove the 'App\UI\Alerts' singleton from ServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I see is that those Alerts are 2 different classes because their namespaces don't match, so I would suggest you take a closer look at the both of them and check out their differences.

Comment: Only the names that the singletons are registered under are different. There's only one class that's constructed here: `App\UI\Alerts`. `Alerts` is simply a name. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The original post has been edited after my response, so that might be the issue, because I would see that only 1 class is being used in both singletons :) PS: I left a comment on the original post, explaining what's up :)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses `$this->app->singleton()` in providers to alias strings to implementations, most often to map interfaces to concrete objects. Here the two statements are different because `'Alerts'` is a different value than `'App\UI\Alerts'`.

```
$this->app->singleton('Alerts', function ($app) {
    return new Alerts;
});
```

allows for you to do this

```
$alerts = app('Alerts');
```

Whereas

```
$this->app->singleton('App\UI\Alerts', function ($app) {
    return $app->make('Alerts');
});
```

Allows you to do this

```
$alerts = app('App\UI\Alerts');
```

This is also commonly combined with `::class` for full class paths.

```
use App\UI\Alerts;
$alerts = app(Alerts::class);
```

Comment: It's still resolving to the exact same object. This probably means the code has both versions of calling the singleton and someone didn't want to refactor the whole project and just registered the same thing under two separate aliases